# Order specific columns in json_agg

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, json

I want to sort the rows inside the json_agg function.

I found this:
[PostgreSQL : select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/postgresql-select-columns-inside-json-agg)

Which gave me a solution to selecting specific columns for json_agg, but now I want to give the aggregated data a specific order. The "distinct" does work the "order by" does not.

```
json_agg(DISTINCT (colA, colB))
```

This does not:

```
json_agg(DISTINCT (colA, colB) ORDER BY colA ASC, colB ASC)
```

Is there a way to sort the aggregated data?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is not `ORDER BY` construct attached to the `DISTINCT` clause directly. There is only the `ORDER BY` attached to the query. Please provide your full query, some sample data the desired result.

Answer (score 10):

Without knowing exactly what you meant by 'The "distinct" does work the "order by" does not.', I guess you get an error:

> ERROR:  in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list

It is more or less self-explanatory.  Try

```
json_agg(DISTINCT (colA, colB) ORDER BY (colA, colB))
```

instead - you don't aggregate individual columns in `json_agg()` but a record, and should order by that one.