# Filter and append data to row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, aggregate, json

My query and my data set ([copied from sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/915c7/6)):

```
CREATE TABLE one (
    id int4 primary key, 
    p_id int4, 
    k_id int4
);
CREATE TABLE two(
   id int4 primary key, 
   p_id int4, 
   k_id int4,
   t_id int4,
   pos int4
);

INSERT INTO one(id, p_id, k_id) VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1), 
    (2, 1, 2), 
    (3, 1, 3), 
    (4, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO two(id, p_id, k_id, t_id, pos) VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), -- t_id = 1 and pos = 1
    (2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
    (3, 1, 3, 1, 1), -- t_id = 1 and pos = 1
    (4, 1, 4, 1, 3),
    (5, 1, 1, 2, 3), -- shares p_id and k_id with row 1
    (6, 1, 2, 2, 1),
    (7, 1, 3, 2, 5), -- shares p_id and k_id with row 3
    (8, 1, 4, 2, 6);
```

Table one is a join table, I've added it because in the future I might add more columns into it, and then it will be easier to modify this report.

What I want is to be able to filter my dataset like so:

1. Get all the rows where pos = 1 for t_id = 1

Expected output:

```
p_id, k_id, stats
1,     1,    [{p_id: 1, k_id: 1, t_id: 1, pos: 1}, {p_id: 1, k_id: 1, t_id: 2, pos: 3}
1,     3,    [{p_id: 1, k_id: 3, t_id: 1, pos: 1}, {p_id: 1, k_id: 3, t_id: 2, pos: 5}
```

As you can see I want to append to my results the data for others `t_ids` where `p_id` and `k_id` are the with the found results.

**Update:**

What will be the best way of removing duplicates?

Adding `(9, 1, 1, 1, 20)` to my dataset will result in having the same type twice in a row;

One solution to get only uniq types and the smallest pos values is:

```
WITH uniqt AS (
  SELECT   p_id, k_id, t_id, min(pos) as pos
  FROM     two
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

)

Because I am selecting from `table one` 50 rows (limit 50) and then join a table with SELECT like in @Erwin Brandstetter example, having this CTE will slow down my query?

Comment: We prefer to have the basic table definition and the query you tried in the question. Also, the fiddle shows aggregated JSON in the result, which you don't mention`?

Comment: Also you don't mention table `one` in your description at all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `inner join` to filter for rows that share a `(p_id, k_id)` value with rows that have a `(t_id, pos)` of `(1,1)` ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5d3539/5/0)):

```
select  base.p_id
,       base.k_id
,       json_agg(base order by base.p_id, base.k_id, base.t_id, base.pos) as stats
from    (
        select  p_id
        ,       k_id
        ,       t_id
        ,       pos
        from    two
        ) base
join    two as filter
on      filter.t_id = 1
        and filter.pos = 1
        and filter.p_id = base.p_id
        and filter.k_id = base.k_id
group by
        base.p_id
,       base.k_id;
```

Or an equivalent way using an `exists` subquery ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5d3539/7/0)):

```
select  base.p_id
,       base.k_id
,       json_agg(base order by base.p_id, base.k_id, base.t_id, base.pos) as stats
from    (
        select  p_id
        ,       k_id
        ,       t_id
        ,       pos
        from    two
        ) base
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    two as filter
        where   filter.t_id = 1
                and filter.pos = 1
                and filter.p_id = base.p_id
                and filter.k_id = base.k_id
        )
group by
        base.p_id
,       base.k_id;
```

Updated to use `json_agg` from @ErwinBrandstetter's answer.

Comment: `json_agg(two)` includes the `id` column that's not supposed to be in the result. That's the second reason for the subquery in my answer (besides the `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear how table `one` is relevant at all. So I am ignoring that table

To build the JSON value you seem to be after (according to the query in the fiddle):

```
SELECT p_id, k_id, json_agg(sub) AS result
FROM  (
   SELECT p_id, k_id, t_id, pos
   FROM   two t2
   WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   two
      WHERE  pos = 1
      AND    t_id = 1
      AND    p_id = t2.p_id
      AND    k_id = t2.k_id
      )
   ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
   ) sub
GROUP  BY p_id, k_id;
```

Produces the desired result exactly.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/915c7/13)

#### Explanation

- The inner query is similar to what [@Andomar already posted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107179/3684): An `EXISTS` semi-join being the key element.
- `ORDER BY` relevant columns right away, that's cheaper than adding an `ORDER BY` clause to the aggregate function.
- Use [`json_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) for the final aggregate. You don't even need `row_to_json()`, just use the alias `sub` of the derived table in the subquery as argument to `json_agg()`.
- In Postgres **9.4** you could use [`json_build_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) to get key names as desired in your JSON document. See:
  [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/postgresql-select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)

Comment: Wouldn't the query optimizer be free to drop the `order by` in the subquery?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Table `one` is a join table, I've added it because in the future I might add more columns into it, and then it will be easier to select lets say a p_id and new_column_id, and get the a report for that selection.

Comment: @Andomar: By strict standard SQL rules, yes. But it works in the Postgres implementation as is [documented here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-aggregate.html): `This ordering is unspecified by default, but can be controlled by writing an ORDER BY clause within the aggregate call, as shown in Section 4.2.7.` **`Alternatively, supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work.`**

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Looks like `json_agg` supports an `order by` clause, like `json_agg(row order by row.col1)`!  That avoids the "will usually work" part.

Comment: @Andomar: (Almost) *all* aggregate functions do (where it makes sense). The point is that per-row `ORDER BY` is more expensive than a single `ORDER BY` in the subquery.