# Avoid joining to the same table multiple times

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, order-by, postgresql-9.4

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE one (
  id int4 primary key,
  p_id int4,
  k_id int4,
  c_id int4
);

CREATE TABLE two(
 id int4 primary key,
 p_id int4,
 k_id int4,
 t_id int4,
 pos int4
);
```

Table `one`: is a join table, I'm using it in this report only because of the `c_id` and to limit the number of row.

Table `two`: contains my data, a `p_id`, `k_id` and `t_id` can have many `pos`, so I'm grouping them and using `min()`, to get the min `pos`. I've tried some ways to get all my data for a `k_id` and `p_id` [here is a way](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107176/filter-and-append-data-to-row) (with this solution I was not able to order by `pos`), so I end up doing this [(see fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ea41c/2):

```
SELECT
  o.p_id,
  o.k_id,
  min(t.pos) as t_pos,
  min(t1.pos) as t1_pos
FROM one o
  LEFT JOIN two t ON t.p_id = o.p_id 
    AND t.k_id = o.k_id
    AND t.t_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN two t1 ON t1.p_id = o.p_id 
    AND t1.k_id = o.k_id
    AND t1.t_id = 2
WHERE o.p_id = 1 AND o.c_id = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2
LIMIT 1
```

This solution is 2-3 times slower then [@Erwin Brandstetter's solution from the other post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107176/filter-and-append-data-to-row), but sorting `t_pos`, `t1_pos` is possible and also getting all data where `type_id = 1` and `pos = 1` for example.

Is there a better way of achieving the same output and improve the speed and be able to sort my data (`t_pos` and `t1_pos` columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try how good this works for you

Converted left join to one inner join for table Two for both t_id's. And on computing min, using case statement to split to two columns based on the value t_id. What we save here is scanning the table two time and an inner join compared to left join

```
SELECT
    o.p_id,
    o.k_id,
    MIN(case when t.t_id = 1 then t.pos else null end) AS t_pos,
    MIN(case when t.t_id = 2 then t.pos else null end) AS t1_pos
FROM
    one o
INNER JOIN two T ON t.p_id = o.p_id
AND t.k_id = o.k_id
AND t.t_id =any ( 1,2)
WHERE
    o.p_id = 1
AND o.c_id = 1
GROUP BY
    1,
    2
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: A few explaining words are always a good idea, just saying.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. And here it comes. Converted left join to one inner join for table Two for both t_id's. And on computing min, using case statement to split to two columns based on the value t_id. What we save here is scanning the table two time and an inner join compared to left join

Comment: It would be much better to edit your answer than add explanation in a comment. Comments are temporary and not searchable.

Comment: @Aneesh Mon N Thanks, this is faster then mine, do you know how can I get for example, all rows where pos = 1 and type = 1?

Comment: Are you looking for adding a having clause to set pos=1 and type =1..? if so, its like below. After group by Add "HAVING MIN(case when t.t_id = 1 then t.pos else null end) =1 AND
    MIN(case when t.t_id = 2 then t.pos else null end) =1

Comment: @Alex, You are welcome...!