# Create smaller row from alias and preserve column names

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, row

Using Postgres:

```
SELECT users."name" AS "name"
    , array_to_json(array_agg(sites)) as sites
FROM remodel.users AS users
JOIN remodel.user_sites AS user_sites
    ON users.id=user_sites.user
JOIN remodel.sites AS sites
    ON sites.id=user_sites.site
GROUP BY "users".id
;
```

currently produces

```json
"Toby";"[{"id":1,"name":"Village","created":"2015-08-10T15:22:36.622298"},
         {"id":2,"name":"Manor","created":"2015-08-10T15:22:43.614551"}]"
"Amy";"[{"id":3,"name":"Park","created":"2015-08-10T15:22:48.810872"}]"
"Anne";"[{"id":2,"name":"Manor","created":"2015-08-10T15:22:43.614551"},
         {"id":1,"name":"Village","created":"2015-08-10T15:22:36.622298"},
         {"id":3,"name":"Park","created":"2015-08-10T15:22:48.810872"}]"
```

however I would like not to have the "id" field in the JSON output.

changing the sites selection to

```
array_to_json(array_agg(row(sites."name", sites.created))) as sites
```

causes the fields to lose their names

```json
"[{"f1":"Village","f2":"2015-08-10T15:22:36.622298"},
  {"f1":"Manor","f2":"2015-08-10T15:22:43.614551"}]"
```

and attempting (what would be a horrible) sub selection

```
, array_to_json(array_agg((SELECT "name", created FROM sites))) as sites
```

understandably throws an

> ERROR: relation "sites" does not exist

And removing the id with a select in the from clause prevents joining the tables.

I'm looking to preserve the column information as well as I can,  not just for conversion to JSON but for inclusion in much larger and complex queries,  so performing the array selection without using JSON is preferred.

Comment: In 9.4 you can use `json_object`, but you'll still have to repeat all the column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to create an inline view containing the columns you are interested in:

```
SELECT users."name" AS "name"
     , array_to_json(array_agg(sites)) as sites
FROM remodel.users AS users
JOIN remodel.user_sites AS user_sites
    ON users.id=user_sites.user
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT name, created 
    FROM remodel.sites AS s
    WHERE s.id=user_sites.site
) AS sites
GROUP BY "users".id
```

By using `LATERAL` you can reference the "sibling" in the inline view. Since the `JOIN` condition is part of the view a `CROSS JOIN` can be used.

Comment: This reply solved the problem and performs better in the benchmarks against my database.  As I have no intention of using JSON returns this is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, a `ROW()` expression does not preserve column names. Use a **subselect** instead.
And [**`json_agg()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is simpler and faster for the task:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
     , json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT s.name, s.created) x)) AS sites
FROM   remodel.users      u
JOIN   remodel.user_sites us ON us.user = u.id
JOIN   remodel.sites      s  ON s.site = us.id
GROUP  BY u.id;  -- id must be the PK
```

The question has been answered before - with detailed explanation and links:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)

---

To preserve column names in a plain array (not JSON or hstore), you need to use a **registered row type** for the row, else column names are lost in any case.
Either you already have a matching row type, or you register one (temporarily):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_site(name text, created timestamptz)  -- use your data types!
```

Then:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
     , array_agg((s.name, s.created)::tmp_site) AS sites  -- or whatever you do with s
FROM   remodel.users      u
JOIN   remodel.user_sites us ON us.user = u.id
JOIN   remodel.sites      s  ON us.site = s.id
GROUP  BY u.id
```

[Details in the linked answer.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)