# Multiple to_json(array_agg), separate joins

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, json, join

I'm building a messaging system, and trying to get a list of messages and their replies; and also join the participants of the message threads.

So I'm shooting for `messages = [{id, subject, body, replies: [..], users: [..]}]`

```
SELECT messages.*, 
       to_json(array_agg(users)) users, 
       to_json(array_agg(replies)) replies
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, fullname, email, company FROM users) users 
   ON users.id = messages.user_id OR users.id = messages.to
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY created_at) replies 
   ON replies.message_id = messages.id
WHERE messages.to = :to OR (messages.to IS NOT NULL AND messages.user_id = :to)
GROUP BY messages.id;
```

I've tried various other queries, this gets me the closest. The problem is that for each message, all the replies are repeated once. I.e., if there are 3 replies in a thread, I get 6 (2x each). Any ideas what might be wrong?

I am using Postgres 9.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is this:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

Here is *one* way to avoid this problem and improve some other details while being at it:

```
SELECT m.*, u.users, r.replies
FROM   messages m
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(u) AS users
   FROM   (
      SELECT id, fullname, email, company
      FROM   users
      WHERE  id IN (m.user_id, m.to)
      -- no order by?
      ) u
   ) u ON TRUE
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(r) AS replies
   FROM   (
      SELECT *
      FROM   messages
      WHERE  message_id = m.id
      ORDER  BY created_at
      ) r
   ) r ON TRUE
WHERE  :to IN (m.user_id, m.to)
AND    m.to IS NOT NULL;
```

- Use [json_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) instead of `to_json(array_agg())`. Simpler, faster.
- Aggregate the subquery on `users` right away in a `LATERAL` join, thus **avoiding the main problem**. Related:

  - [Create smaller row from alias and preserve column names](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110613/create-smaller-row-from-alias-and-preserve-column-names/110680#110680)
- This:

  ```
  WHERE  m.to = :to OR
        (m.to IS NOT NULL AND m.user_id = :to)
  ```

  can be expressed simpler:

  ```
  WHERE  :to IN (m.user_id, m.to)
  AND    m.to IS NOT NULL
  ```
- This:

  ```
  SELECT json_agg(r) AS replies
  FROM   (
     SELECT *
     FROM   messages
     WHERE  message_id = m.id
     ORDER  BY created_at
     ) r
  ```

  *could* be shortened to:

  ```
  SELECT json_agg(r ORDER BY created_at) AS replies
  FROM   messages r
  WHERE  message_id = m.id
  ```

But a single `ORDER BY` in a subquery is typically faster than per-aggregate `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks a million, that's the ticket! Noted on including version, will do next time.