# Why does json_agg fail with error "function json_agg(record) does not exist"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

With postgresql version 9.2, I'm trying to run a query that selects certain columns to build a json object. Here's the query, which I derived from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg):

```
select
  a.id
  , json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT b.fieldA) AS x)) AS item
from a join b on a.id = b.foreign_key
limit 10
```

When I run this, I get an error that's rather hard to parse.

> ERROR: function json_agg(record) does not exist   Hint: No function
>   matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
>   explicit type casts.
>
> , json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT b.fieldA) AS x)) AS item

It seems as though the complaint is that json_agg is not receiving the right sort of input, but I don't understand why.

When I run the same query without the `json_agg`, i.e. just with the sub-select expression, I get a column with the value of `b.fieldA` inside parentheses. I'm not sure what the parens indicate in terms of a data type, but I could see that perhaps `json_agg` is only getting the values an so doesn't know how to supply the property name.

Can anyone explain where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_agg does not exist in postgres version 9.2 (which is now at end-of-life).  It was introduced in version 9.3.

The HINT does seem to be slightly inappropriate. If no function by that name exists, then no amount of casting the arguments can work.