# to_json vs ::json in postgres

Tags: postgresql, json

I was wondering how to address the `tsrange` problem in postgres, as `tsrange('2010-01-01 14:30', '2010-01-01 15:30')::json` returns annoying escapes: `"[\"2010-01-01 14:30:00\",\"2010-01-01 15:30:00\")"`. [Postgres REST](http://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/how-tos/casting-type-to-custom-json.html) nicely suggest to approach the problem through automatic casts:

```
create or replace function tsrange_to_json(tsrange) returns json as $$
  select json_build_object(
    'lower', lower($1)
  , 'upper', upper($1)
  , 'lower_inc', lower_inc($1)
  , 'upper_inc', upper_inc($1)
  );
$$ language sql;
create cast (tsrange as json) with function tsrange_to_json(tsrange) as assignment;
```

which works nicely if I cast `tsrange::json` but keeps the old formatting if I do `to_json(tsrange)`

```
select tsrange('2010-01-01 14:30', '2010-01-01 15:30')::json
-- "{"lower" : "2010-01-01T14:30:00", "upper" : "2010-01-01T15:30:00", "lower_inc" : true, "upper_inc" : false}"
select to_json(tsrange('2010-01-01 14:30', '2010-01-01 15:30'))
-- ""[\"2010-01-01 14:30:00\",\"2010-01-01 15:30:00\")""
```

Why `to_json` does not use `::json` casts?

Comment: Because `to_json()` is not a cast. It's a conversion function similar to `to_date()` or `to_char()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for the hint. Is there any way to expand on your answer in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200240/28367 to elegantly solve `to_jsonb(b) - 'item_id'` where b contains tsranges. Because now it just makes strings inside with lots of escapes?