# Combining table under different alias

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-12

I have two tables trips and users. Whenever an user posts a trip, it stores id of the user as foreign key. And while fetching, I am joining those two tables the following way.

Query:

```
SELECT title, starting_point, ending_point, distance, trips.created_on 
FROM trips 
  JOIN users ON (users.id=trips.created_by);
```

Result:

```
{
            "title": "lorem ipsum",
            "starting_point": "Location A",
            "ending_point": "Location B",
            "distance": 20,
            "created_on": "2020-07-27T18:15:00.000Z",
            "author": "Test user"
        },
```

Result needed.

```
{
            "title": "lorem ipsum",
            "starting_point": "Location A",
            "ending_point": "Location B",
            "distance": 20,
            "created_on": "2020-07-27T18:15:00.000Z",
            "author": {
                       "id":1
                       "name": "Test user",
                       "role": "admin"
                      }
        },
```

In short, I want to join user table with trips table but I want to separate the content of user table in different alias in trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Whole row

You don't mention JSON, but it seems you are after [`to_json(b)()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) or similar. Example:

```sql
SELECT t.*, to_json(u) AS author
FROM   trips t
JOIN   users u ON u.id = t.created_by;
```

**Or**, without involving JSON:

```sql
SELECT t.*, u AS author
FROM   trips t
JOIN   users u ON u.id = t.created_by;
```

Then `author` is a ROW value, but without column names - that information is only in the definition of the row type.

#### Selected columns

You later commented:

> ... if I want `id`, `email` and `name` only from `users` table?

JSON:

```sql
SELECT t.*
     , json_build_object('id', u.id, 'email', u.email, 'name', u.name)) AS author
FROM   trips t
JOIN   users u ON u.id = t.created_by;
```

Or ROW value:

```sql
SELECT t.*
    , (SELECT x FROM (SELECT u.id, u.email, u.name) AS x)) AS author
FROM   trips t
JOIN   users u ON u.id = t.created_by;
```

See:

- [Return as array of JSON objects in SQL (Postgres)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486910/939860)
- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)
- [Raw SQL queries in a REST Api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27515253/939860)

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't quite know how to phrase my question in this case. Thank you very much for the answer. Now I know where to look for any further issues. Have a nice day good sir.

Comment: Do you happen to know how do I select the element on to_json function? like if I want id, email and name only from users table.

Comment: @ZeroLive: I added another answer. Also consider the linked answers. Please remember to ask new questions as new *question*. Comments are not the place.

Comment: Sure. I will keep that in mind. Thank you very much.